# Qt and OpenCV 2.0 integration problems

Tags: qt, opencv, signals-slots

I have a Qt application that uses OpenCV for image processing.

Everything was working fine with OpenCV 1.0 but when I upgraded to
OpenCV 2.0 it started crashing.
I noticed that it only crashes whenever OpenCV functions are called
inside Qt slots.

For instance, the following slot:

```
void TestClass::on_testButton_clicked() {
   IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("test.jpg");
   IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), src->depth, src->nChannels);
   cvThreshold(src, dst, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
}
```

crashes when testButton is clicked.

However, if I call the same cvThreshold function in any other place,
such as inside the main() function
or inside the Widget constructor, it works fine. Also, if I put the
same code in a separate function and
call that function with QtConcurrent::run() inside the same slot, it
works fine too.

Why this behaviour? Are there any restrictions about the operations
that can be done inside Qt slots? Which changes in OpenCV 2.0 functions
may be causing the conflict?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I was using OpenCV's precompiled libraries,
which were created with a different version of mingw.

I compiled the library with cmake+mingw and using
the generated libraries solved the problem.

Comment: don't forget to accept your answer if it solves your problem.. that way the question won't be marked "unanswered" .. plus, you'll get a badge. :)

Comment: @Andres: How did you manage to compile opencv+Qt with cmake+mingw? If I try that, I get an error that a file named `Windows-gcc.cmake` is missing.